# Prolog. Как добавить несколько элементов в конец списка.

Tags: prolog

```
add(E,[],[E]). 
add(E,[H|T],[H|T1]):-add(E,T,T1).
answer(Ct, List, Answers) :-   (Ct > 4),! ; write('Input answer '), write(Ct), write(': '), read(Str), add( Str, List, Answers), Ct1 is Ct + 1, answer(Ct1, Answers, Answers).
```

Answers - результирующий список
но в итоге не получается.

Comment: Что именно должен делать предикат answer? Каков смысл переменных Str и Ct?

Comment: предикат answer - добавлять в список Answers ответы, при этом в конец, Ct - счётчик

Comment: Str - введённых элемент, да названия не ахти

Comment: Хорошо, а зачем сравнение с 4?

Comment: ну типо ввести только 4 элемента можно

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас отвечу.

Comment: как вариант думаю модифицировать add под данную задачу

Answer (score 3):

```
add(E,[],[E]). 
add(E,[H|T],[H|T1]):-add(E,T,T1).

readupto4(NewElements) :- write('Input the number of elements '), 
                          read(NumberOfElements),
                          (NumberOfElements =< 4 ->
                               readupto4(NumberOfElements,NewElements)
                           ; (write('Wrong number of elements entered. 
                                     The input list will not be modified.'),
                              NewElements = [])).
readupto4(NumberOfElements,[NewElement|NewElements]) :-
                          NumberOfElements > 0, !,
                          write('Input value :'), read(NewElement),
                          NumberOfElements1 is NumberOfElements - 1,
                          readupto4(NumberOfElements1,NewElements).
readupto4(0, []).

answer(OldList,NewList) :- readupto4(NewElements), add(OldList,NewElements,NewList).
```

Если число элементов не ограничено четвёркой, то

```
readupto4(NewElements) :- write('Input the number of elements '), 
                          read(NumberOfElements),
                          readupto4(NumberOfElements,NewElements).
```

Comment: спасибо вам, просто структурное программирование бьёт в голову вот и туплю

Comment: @shkiper ну структурное-то программирование не виновато. Проблема стандартна. Если человек изучал (а тем более имеет опыт программирования) императивное программирование, то декларативное ему будет даваться с трудом. Идеальная ситуация для демонстрации проблемы: стартовый язык -- язык ассемблера.